# Scala type projection with higher-kinded type

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types, type-projection

Consider the following:

```
trait Foo {
  type F[_]
  type A
  type FA = F[A]
  def get: FA
}

class SeqStringFoo extends Foo {
  type F[_] = Seq[_]
  type A = String
  def get: Seq[String] = Seq("hello world")
}

def exec[F <: Foo](foo: F): F#FA = foo.get

val seq1: Seq[Any] = exec(new SeqStringFoo()) // Seq[Any] = List(hello world)
val seq2: Seq[String] = exec(new SeqStringFoo()) // Error: Expression SeqIntFoo#FA doesn't conform to Seq[String]
```

`seq2` doesn't compile since for some reason, type information of wrapped type `String` is lost when using **type projection** `F#FA`.

This doesn't happen when returned type **isn't** higher-kinded type.

Why does this happen?

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look like you just forgot pass type variable for F[_] in specialization, try:

```
class SeqStringFoo extends Foo {
  type F[x] = Seq[x]
  type A = String
  def get: FA = Seq("hello world")
}
```

in other case you always return `Seq[_]` ( == `Seq[Any]`) for any `F[_]` (`F[Int]`, `F[String]`)

Comment: Didn't even know such thing as `type variable` existed. Learning new everyday. Thank you!